# Converting the current time to an Int (Haskell)

Tags: haskell, time, io

I've been searching for ages to try and find an easy way to take the current time (could be seconds since midnight, or hour, min, sec) to an int.
Could anyone point me in the right direction? I've looked in the libraries and had no success.

Comment: I don't program in Haskell but have been looking for similar information in other languages. How about toSeconds? http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/datetime/0.1/doc/html/Data-DateTime.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the time since midnight as an `Int` is pretty easy:

```
import Data.Time.Clock
main = do
  currTime <- getCurrentTime
  let timed = floor $ utctDayTime currTime :: Int
  print timed
```

For kicks and giggles, here's a quick function for it

```
integralTime :: (Integral a) => IO a
integralTime = getCurrentTime >>= return.floor.utctDayTime
```

This works since `TimeDiff` (it's a `RealFrac` instance) can be `floor`ed to an integral.

Comment: Perhaps worth saying that this uses `Data.Time.Clock` (though that can easily be [Hoogled](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=utctDayTime)).

Comment: Also, the `toRational` isn't necessary: `floor` is already polymorphic on any `RealFrac` argument.

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting this error:  No instance for (RealFrac DiffTime) arising from a use of `floor'

Comment: Weird,what version of GHC/Data.time do you have? Otherwise you can always use th emroe verbose `floor.toRational`

Comment: I'm using ghc 7.04. I also have a portable version of 7.6.2 and wierdly, it compiles with 7.6.2. However I can't use this version because it doesn't have the System.Random library included. floor.toRational spews more errors. Maybe I should just use 7.6.2 but I'll need to find a way to import System.Random, I didn't have any luck when I tried to import it before

Comment: Yep, time is updated in 7.6 (it's what I use) You can easily get it with cabal if you like. Also what errors to using toRational spew?

Comment: I just installed Haskell Platform which I guess includes System.Random and the updated Data.Time because it works! Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem! Have fun with Haskell!

Comment: I have one more question, it seems that I can't return this int for us in another function since its wrapped in IO. How can I make it just an integer?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26825/discussion-between-jozefg-and-joe)

Answer (score 0):

My first hit on Google when searching for "haskell datetime" was the same link as Tim gives. There you have `getCurrentTime :: IO DateTime` to get the current time, and then `diffUTCTime :: UTCTime -> UTCTime -> NominalDiffTime` to calculate a difference (treated as seconds).

http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/datetime/0.1/doc/html/Data-DateTime.html
http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/time/1.1.4/doc/html/Data-Time-Clock.html#t:UTCTime